# Add some grouping columns to a nested dataframe in R

Tags: r, nested, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe in R with 3 columns (variables). One of them, called Region, is some kind nested.
I try to reproduce a little part of it.

```
df <- data.frame (freq = c(70, 72, 74, 76, 78,
                           70, 72, 74, 76, 78,
                           70, 72, 74, 76, 78),
                  region = c('region.1','region.1','region.1','region.1', 'region.1',
                             'region.1.1','region.1.1','region.1.1', 'region.1.1', 'region.1.1',
                             'region.2','region.2', 'region.2', 'region.2', 'region.2'),
                  dBvalue = c(-30, -32, -42, -45, -47,
                              -33, -28, -22, -37, -35,
                              -36, -55, -43, -26, -49))
```

Now I want to add 3 new colums.
The first with the count of the observations per region (so in this case will be 1...5, 1...5, etc),
the second must contain a grouping value,
ant the last should have the higher hierarchical level of aggregation of the Region column
in this case the final df would be:

```
df <- data.frame (freq = c(70, 72, 74, 76, 78,
                           70, 72, 74, 76, 78,
                           70, 72, 74, 76, 78),
                  region = c('region.1','region.1','region.1','region.1', 'region.1',
                             'region.1.1','region.1.1','region.1.1', 'region.1.1', 'region.1.1',
                             'region.2','region.2', 'region.2', 'region.2', 'region.2'),
                  dBvalue = c(-30, -32, -42, -45, -47,
                              -33, -28, -22, -37, -35,
                              -36, -55, -43, -26, -49),
                  count = c(1,2,3,4,5,
                            1,2,3,4,5,
                            1,2,3,4,5),
                  group = c(1,1,1,1,1,
                            2,2,2,2,2,
                            3,3,3,3,3),
                  higher_region = c("region.1","region.1","region.1","region.1","region.1",
                  "region.1","region.1","region.1","region.1","region.1",
                  "region.2","region.2","region.2","region.2","region.2"))
```

I'm trying with loop functions but i'm going crazy. Someone has a solution? Maybe using alternative methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Base* you can use `match` with `unique` to find the *group*, `ave` with `seq_along` to get the *count* and `strsplit` with `paste` to get the *higher_region*.

```
df$group <- match(df$region, unique(df$region))
#df$group <- unclass(factor(df$region)) #Alternative
df$count <- ave(df$group, df$region, FUN=seq_along)
df$higher_region <- sapply(strsplit(df$region, ".", TRUE),
 function(x) paste(x[1:2], collapse = "."))
#df$higher_region <- sub("^([^.]+\\.[^.]*).*", "\\1", df$region) #Alternative
df
#   freq     region dBvalue count group higher_region
#1    70   region.1     -30     1     1      region.1
#2    72   region.1     -32     2     1      region.1
#3    74   region.1     -42     3     1      region.1
#4    76   region.1     -45     4     1      region.1
#5    78   region.1     -47     5     1      region.1
#6    70 region.1.1     -33     1     2      region.1
#7    72 region.1.1     -28     2     2      region.1
#8    74 region.1.1     -22     3     2      region.1
#9    76 region.1.1     -37     4     2      region.1
#10   78 region.1.1     -35     5     2      region.1
#11   70   region.2     -36     1     3      region.2
#12   72   region.2     -55     2     3      region.2
#13   74   region.2     -43     3     3      region.2
#14   76   region.2     -26     4     3      region.2
#15   78   region.2     -49     5     3      region.2
```

Comment: I prefer your `group` & `count` base solution over mine. But My `higher_region` base solution is simpler `sub("(region\\.\\d+).*","\\1",df$region)`

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion using 'dplyr' for the grouping and counting, as well as 'as.factor' to 'recode' the regions into "he second must contain a grouping value" (although this encodes the *same* information as 'region', maybe I misunderstood your specification. Finally we use 'gsub' to extract the first digit from 'region'

```
df <- data.frame (freq = c(70, 72, 74, 76, 78,
                           70, 72, 74, 76, 78,
                           70, 72, 74, 76, 78),
                  region = c('region.1','region.1','region.1','region.1', 'region.1',
                             'region.1.1','region.1.1','region.1.1', 'region.1.1', 'region.1.1',
                             'region.2','region.2', 'region.2', 'region.2', 'region.2'),
                  dBvalue = c(-30, -32, -42, -45, -47,
                              -33, -28, -22, -37, -35,
                              -36, -55, -43, -26, -49))

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  mutate(count = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(group = as.numeric(as.factor(region)),
         higher_region = gsub("[a-z.]*([0-9]).*", "\\1", region)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

Returns:

> ```
>    freq     region dBvalue count group higher_region
> 1    70   region.1     -30     1     1             1
> 2    72   region.1     -32     2     1             1
> 3    74   region.1     -42     3     1             1
> 4    76   region.1     -45     4     1             1
> 5    78   region.1     -47     5     1             1
> 6    70 region.1.1     -33     1     2             1
> 7    72 region.1.1     -28     2     2             1
> 8    74 region.1.1     -22     3     2             1
> 9    76 region.1.1     -37     4     2             1
> 10   78 region.1.1     -35     5     2             1
> 11   70   region.2     -36     1     3             2
> 12   72   region.2     -55     2     3             2
> 13   74   region.2     -43     3     3             2
> 14   76   region.2     -26     4     3             2
> 15   78   region.2     -49     5     3             2
> ```

## Edit:

Account for two digit 'higher regions':

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  mutate(count = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(group = as.numeric(as.factor(region)),
         higher_region = gsub("(region.[0-9]+)\\.?.*", "\\1", region)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()


   freq     region dBvalue count group higher_region
1    70   region.1     -30     1     1      region.1
2    72   region.1     -32     2     1      region.1
3    74   region.1     -42     3     1      region.1
4    76   region.1     -45     4     1      region.1
5    78   region.1     -47     5     1      region.1
6    70 region.1.1     -33     1     2      region.1
7    72 region.1.1     -28     2     2      region.1
8    74 region.1.1     -22     3     2      region.1
9    76 region.1.1     -37     4     2      region.1
10   78 region.1.1     -35     5     2      region.1
11   70   region.2     -36     1     3      region.2
12   72   region.2     -55     2     3      region.2
13   74   region.2     -43     3     3      region.2
14   76   region.2     -26     4     3      region.2
15   78   region.2     -49     5     3      region.2
```

Comment: it seems to work until the region values has only one digit in the first part; when I have, for example, the region 10.3 it assigns this to higher_region 1 instead of 10

Comment: Maybe could it be easier if I rename region value with a different syntax? for example: region 1, region 1_1, region 1_2, ..., region 12_3?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you want 'higher_region' for, but I added an edit to my answer with code that should work with 'region.11.1' etc.

Comment: "higher_region" should contain the word 'region', the point and the first number. So in the case of region value 'region.12.1', higher_region' will be region.12. Now I'm trying your solutions, thank you

Answer (score 1):

additional option. `dplyr 1.0.0`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  mutate(count = row_number(),
         group = cur_group_id(),
         higher_region = str_extract(region, "^[A-z]*\\.\\d+")) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
within(df, {
    region_str <- as.character(region)
    higher_region <- ifelse(grepl("[.]\\d[.]", region_str),
                            gsub("[.]\\d$", "", region_str), region_str)
    count <- ave(region_str, region_str, FUN = length)
    rm(region_str)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
df$count <- unlist(lapply(split(df,df$region), function(x) 1:nrow(x)))
df$group <- unlist(lapply(1:length(unique(df$region)), function(x) rep(x, nrow(split(df,df$region)[[x]]))))
df$higher_region <- sub("(region\\.\\d+).*","\\1",df$region)

> df
   freq     region dBvalue count group higher_region
1    70   region.1     -30     1     1      region.1
2    72   region.1     -32     2     1      region.1
3    74   region.1     -42     3     1      region.1
4    76   region.1     -45     4     1      region.1
5    78   region.1     -47     5     1      region.1
6    70 region.1.1     -33     1     2      region.1
7    72 region.1.1     -28     2     2      region.1
8    74 region.1.1     -22     3     2      region.1
9    76 region.1.1     -37     4     2      region.1
10   78 region.1.1     -35     5     2      region.1
11   70   region.2     -36     1     3      region.2
12   72   region.2     -55     2     3      region.2
13   74   region.2     -43     3     3      region.2
14   76   region.2     -26     4     3      region.2
15   78   region.2     -49     5     3      region.2
```